# Fetch advertisement data using the Web Bluetooth API

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I have been trying to fetch the nearby BLE advertisements using Web Bluetooth API. I have been been following the steps in this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web).

It has been mentioned in the link that, in order to scan nearby BLE advertisements **navigator.bluetooth.requestLEScan()** can be used in the near future.

I am able to discover the list of near by devices using this API and pair to the devices individually.

Is there a way to get nearby BLE advertisements without pairing to devices individually? Also is **requestLEScan()** implemented or still in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice` is available on most platforms, but `requestLEScan` is [not implemented as of June 2019](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#scanning-api).  The [implementation has been started](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/bluetooth/bluetooth.idl?q=f:%5C.idl%20requestLEScan), but there's no estimated time to completion.